# present(_:animated:completion:) not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

So, when I try to use the present() function in Swift, it always crashes. Here's my code

```
func infoOpener(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    let location: CGPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)

    let cellPath: IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)!


    let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userInfo") as! userInfoVC

    VC.username = "@\(self.user[cellPath.row].username)"
    VC.imageUrl = self.user[cellPath.row].imagePath


    self.present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Whenever I use the `present(_:animated:completion:)` function, I get an EXC_BREAKPOINT error. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: first ensure that object of your VC is properly created or not. I mean check object `VC` is nil or not.

Comment: set a breakpoint before the call of self and check if your VC is nil

Comment: Please check data your are sending is proper by printing them and cellPath value is proper or not because code is correct

Comment: What does the crash report say in the console?

Comment: Please share the full stack trace and crash report.

Comment: VC is definitely not nil

Comment: I am getting this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: When you get the crash, you can inspect the variables in the console. Check which one is `nil` and fix it.

Comment: @ShilpaKakodkar On which line you are getting error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil`

Comment: @redent84 How do I do that?

Comment: @NiravD I'm not sure, but I think it is the present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil) line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if let` or `guard let` instead of force unwrapping Optionals with `!` to make your code more robust:

```
func infoOpener(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    let location: CGPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)

    guard let cellPath: IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
       print("No index path found")
       return
    }

    guard let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userInfo") as? userInfoVC else {
        print("View controller could not be instantiated")
        return
    }

    VC.username = "@\(self.user[cellPath.row].username)"
    VC.imageUrl = self.user[cellPath.row].imagePath


    self.present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func infoOpener(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

            let location: CGPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)
            let cellPath: IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)!

            if sender.state == .ended /*present in touch end*/  {
                let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userInfo") as! userInfoVC
                VC.username = "@\(self.user[cellPath.row].username)"
                VC.imageUrl = self.user[cellPath.row].imagePath
                self.present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It crashed again. Anything else?

Comment: where you declare cellPath variable ?

Comment: where actually is your method infoOpener ...  normally self.present gives us error when self if not a viewcontroller .. so can you please check the scope of self...

Answer (score 0):

You say your error is: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
The problem is probably not with present() method but some IBOutlet or variable on your ViewController. 
Check all your outlets are connected properly or that what you are setting on "username" and "imageURL" is not nil if this variables do not accept nil.